# Jest assert on style after animate is performed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a React Application using Jest and React Testing Library for unit testing. I have difficulties asserting that a component's style has changed. My component takes in an `isSelected` boolean and performs an animation based on that.

My component: (Using [framer-motion](https://www.framer.com/docs/examples/))

```
const MotionImage = motion(Image);

const SCALE_SIZE = 1.5;

export interface IPreviewer{
  isSelected: boolean;
}

export function Previewer({
  isSelected,
}: IPreviewer): JSX.Element {

  return (
    <MotionImage
      animate={{
        scale: isSelected ? SCALE_SIZE : 1,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

My test:

```
test("Component when isSelected highlights the image", () => {
  const { debug } = render(
    <Previewer
      isSelected
    />
  );

  const image = screen.getByRole("img");

  debug(image);

  expect(image).toHaveStyle("transform: scale(1.5) translateZ(0)");
});
```

The test debug giving me:

```
     <img
       class="chakra-image css-yk396h"
       src="http://placeimg.com/222.07846627773333/3.4102996091771587"
       style="transform: none;"
      />
```

As you can see the `img` is found but the style is not as expected:  `style="transform: none;"`

**I will appreciate any suggestions on how to test this right?**

**Note**

Setting `initial={false}` to the component itself will make the test pass but will lose the initial animation so I will avoid that.

Introducing a timeOut promise inside the test before asserting will work, but I would like to avoid that as well.

Answer (score 0):

`waitFor` should help you to wait for the styles. https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor

Comment: Tried doing this: 
await waitFor(() =>
    expect(image).toHaveStyle("transform: scale(1.5) translateZ(0)")
  ) but the result was the same.

Comment: Just a suggestion: maybe increasing a timeout will help. `await waitFor(() => expect(image).toHaveStyle("transform: scale(1.5) translateZ(0)"), { timeout: 3000 } )`

Comment: I bet that would work but I'm not interested in a using timeout as mentioned. Thanks for your input though. Please continue if you have any other suggestions